# regsvr32 and windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, regsvr32

My project uses several dll files with activex controls.

Now I am making a deployment project (windows installer).

I need to register dlls via windows installer using regsvr32. How should I do it ? And can I detect if regsvr32 failed or not ?

Comment: ahem. 8 questions before this one, and not one answer accepted?

Comment: "Accept answer" is some kind of option ? i noticed that some answers have green borders. Do you mean it ?

Comment: check in the faq - basically, you have the ability to tick next to one answer, to indicate that it's been the most helpful one to you.

Comment: oh, ok. I try it right now ;)

greetings from russia!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume when you say you're creating a deployment project, you're talking about the nasty piece of work that's available in Visual Studio?

If so, for each DLL, you can look at their properties, and set the "Register" property to COM.

If you're using some other deployment technology (e.g. Wix, InstallShield, etc), then the answer will vary, but most of these have a simple setting to say "this is an COM dll that needs to be registered", rather than you having to kick off regsvr32.

As to detecting failure - by using the built in facilities, the COM registration takes place during the normal install process, and failures cause the install to rollback - there's no need to check this yourself; in much the same way that you don't have to check that your files made it to the install location, and don't have to worry that the disk was full.

Comment: by the way, why do your avatar look simular to Charles Gargent one ?

Comment: @Alexander - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, seems like you know the theme.

When I uninstall my program, is uninstaller unregister COM dlls automatically ? Or should I additionally check some option or make some setting ?

Comment: @Alexander - It should all just work when you install/uninstall. There shouldn't be any other options to set (why would you ever set it to register but not unregister, or vice versa?)

Comment: (Why would my boss set :D ...)
They can ask me about this option => so I should know an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use `regsvr32` to register a COM interface during an install is, don't. (grin)

Calling `regsvr32` and other forms of "self-registration" during Windows Installer-based installs is bad practice. COM interfaces are often shared between multiple products. If package A registers COM interface `IFoo`, then package B (re)registers the same interface, then if either package is uninstalled and unregisters `IFoo` it breaks the remaining package.

The preferred method is to extract the COM interface information and build it into Registry table entries in the `.msi` package. MSI recognizes matched COM Registry entries and manages a reference count of them rather than duplicating them. The 2nd..Nth entry just bumps the reference count, each uninstall merely decrements it, until the last uninstall decrements the ref-count to zero and Registry entries are actually removed.

In WiX, the [heat](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) tool is used to "harvest" COM interfaces (among other data) into WiX source fragments containing the necessary Registry entries. Installshield has a "COM extract at build" flag that does the same thing for MSI and Installscript-MSI projects. Other Windows Installer toolsets have similar capabilities.

---

Note: Windows Installer(MSI) is the underlying installation-management API that is part of Windows itself. You need additional tools to generate `.msi` packages that use this API.

Windows Installer XML (WiX) is an XML schema for describing MSI-based install packages, along with tools to generate the actual `.msi` package from documents in that schema. Installshield is another tool that can generate `.msi` packages.

Those are the two that I have used. There are other tools such as InstallAware and Advanced Installer. I cannot speak to their capabilities, having never used them myself. Visual Studio also has a plug-in to generate install packages, but in my experience it scales poorly to industrial-strength products.

Comment: From what I have learned this isn't as clear cut a case as one may initially be led to believe. Some COM servers are only installed by their vendor, and even when shared, they're still installed with vendor's procedure, meaning that the vendor is in their right to actually add/remove their own COM server, *without* reference counting. But even if, for some exotic reason, it requires reference counting, it can be done with the same success as WI can do. `DllRegisterServer` isn't going anywhere, it seems: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/implementing-dllregisterserver

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) It is an open source project by MS that creates windows installers (.msi) There is a tool with that called heat that generates code on different inputs, one of which is dll registers etc. The installer framework will take care of whether proper registration has occurred

Comment: Thank you, but my current employer want to use windows installer. I can't argue with them.

Comment: If by windows installer you mean the setup project that VS creates then no this is different, however there is project called votive that is a plugin to VS that allows you to create WiX setups with VS. Take a look, WiX is by far a much more configurable approach to authoring .msi setups.

Comment: WiX's primary goal *is* to build Windows Installer packages, also known as MSI files. In fact, without WiX, you'd be hard pressed to "use" Windows Installer to author packages -- there are APIs but I, for one, have no idea which ones just let you inspect an MSI package, and if there are any APIs that actually let you compile one, or if one needs to know the intricacies of COM structured storage and/or anything else.