# COM object registration

Tags: com, installation

We have a setup package. Our application is using few shared COM objects. We need to install and register them. On some occasions, these COM objects could not be installed and registered. Probably they are locked / used by some other process. So, we are installing the new COM object with different name and then activating reboot in our setup. During reboot we are renaming the COM objects to the original name. This has been done via putting a batch file and register it with runoncekey.

Are there any best practices to register COM objects during restart? We can do this by adding the Regsvr32 to the batch file. But i would like to know whether Microsoft recommends any other methods.

Thanks in advance for your reply,

Comment: This makes little sense, you can't get the required UAC elevation to register the component from the runonce key.  If it works anyway then you are doing something pretty unusual, you need to document that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what technology you are using to implement the installation. While you can certainly use a batch file to do this, I wouldn't.

Instead I would determine what processes might be running that are locking the objects, and have them terminate, so that you don't have to go through the rename.

You might check the responses to this question: [regsvr32 and windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506058/regsvr32-and-windows-installer).

I would use something that can create an MSI package: WIX, InstallShield, etc.  This will both help to manage the running processes and handle the registration.

Comment: Thanks for all for your replies. We are using custom installer where we using self registration of COM objects. We are using Delphi 2010